# Array only listing the first item. (Python)

Tags: python, arrays

Array only listing the first item, I have no idea what I have done wrong at all so I have given every part of my code. The program is supposed to make a list and ask you if you want to make another and so on untill it has done that 10 times (This works) the part that breaks is when I use this part:

```
for a in list1:
 print ("• {}".format(a))
```

every time it tries to list it, it will only list the first item.
PS: I'm only new to programming so please don't be too harsh. Thank you.

```
import time
def function1():
  function =input("Please enter a function. ")
  function_options='view','edit','newlist'
  while function  not in function_options:
    function =input("Please enter a function, if you do not know what a function is then please read the tutorial.  ")
    if function  in function_options:
      break
    else:
      function =input("Please enter a function, if you do not know what a function is then please read the tutorial. ")
      function1()
  if function == 'newlist':
    print ("no")
  elif function == 'view':
    listselect = input("Which list would you like to view? ")
    if listselect == var1:
      for a in list1:
        print ("• {}".format(a))
        function1()
    elif listselect == var2:
      for b in list2:
        print ("• {}".format(b))
        function1()
    elif listselect == var3:
      for c in list3:
        print ("• {}".format(c))
        function1()
    elif listselect == var4:
      for d in list4:
        print ("• {}".format(d))
        function1()
    elif listselect == var5:
      for e in list5:
        print ("• {}".format(e))
        function1()
    elif listselect == var6:
      for f in list6:
        print ("• {}".format(f))
        function1()
    elif listselect == var7:
      for g in list7:
        print ("• {}".format(g))
        function1()
    elif listselect == var8:
      for h in list8:
        print ("• {}".format(h))
        function1()
    elif listselect == var9:
      for i in list9:
        print ("• {}".format(i))
        function1()
    elif listselect == var10:
      for j in list10:
        print ("• {}".format(j))
        function1()

  elif function == 'edit':
   editoption = input("Add or remove items? a/r ")
   if editoption == 'a':
     listselect = input("Which list would you like to add to? ")
     if listselect == var1:
       for a in list1:
         print ("• {}".format(a))
       print ("What would you like to call your new item?")
       additem1 = str(input())
       list1.append(additem1)
       for a in list1:
         print ("• {}".format(a))
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var2:
       for b in list2:
         print ("• {}".format(b))
       print ("What would you like to call your new item?")
       additem2 = str(input())
       list2.append(additem2)
       for b in list2:
         print ("• {}".format(b))
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var3:
       for c in list3:
         print ("• {}".format(c))
       print ("What would you like to call your new item?")
       additem3 = str(input())
       list3.append(additem3)
       for c in list3:
         print ("• {}".format(c))
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var4:
       for d in list4:
         print ("• {}".format(d))
       print ("What would you like to call your new item?")
       additem4 = str(input())
       list4.append(additem4)
       for d in list4:
         print ("• {}".format(d))
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var5:
       for e in list5:
         print ("• {}".format(e))
       print ("What would you like to call your new item?")
       additem5 = str(input())
       list5.append(additem5)
       for e in list5:
         print ("• {}".format(e))
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var6:
       for f in list6:
         print ("• {}".format(f))
       print ("What would you like to call your new item?")
       additem6 = str(input())
       list6.append(additem6)
       for f in list6:
         print ("• {}".format(f))
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var7:
       for g in list7:
         print ("• {}".format(g))
       print ("What would you like to call your new item?")
       additem7 = str(input())
       list7.append(additem7)
       for g in list7:
         print ("• {}".format(g))
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var8:
       for h in list7:
         print ("• {}".format(h))
       print ("What would you like to call your new item?")
       additem7 = str(input())
       list7.append(additem7)
       for h in list7:
         print ("• {}".format(h))
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var9:
       for i in list7:
         print ("• {}".format(i))
       print ("What would you like to call your new item?")
       additem7 = str(input())
       list7.append(additem7)
       for i in list7:
         print ("• {}".format(i))
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var10:
       for j in list7:
         print ("• {}".format(j))
       print ("What would you like to call your new item?")
       additem7 = str(input())
       list7.append(additem7)
       for j in list7:
         print ("• {}".format(j))
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
   elif editoption == 'r':
     listselect = input("Which list would you like to remove items from? ")
     if listselect == var1:
       for a in list1:
         print ("• {}".format(a))
       print ("Which item would you like to remove?")
       removeitem1 = int(input())
       removeitem1 = removeitem1+1
       list1.remove(list1[removeitem1])
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var2:
       for a in list2:
         print ("• {}".format(a))
       print ("Which item would you like to remove?")
       removeitem2 = int(input())
       removeitem2 = removeitem2+1
       list2.remove(list1[removeitem2])
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var3:
       for a in list3:
         print ("• {}".format(a))
       print ("Which item would you like to remove?")
       removeitem3 = int(input())
       removeitem3 = removeitem3+1
       list3.remove(list3[removeitem3])
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var4:
       for a in list4:
         print ("• {}".format(a))
       print ("Which item would you like to remove?")
       removeitem4 = int(input())
       removeitem4 = removeitem4+1
       list4.remove(list4[removeitem4])
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var5:
       for a in list5:
         print ("• {}".format(a))
       print ("Which item would you like to remove?")
       removeitem5 = int(input())
       removeitem5 = removeitem5+1
       list5.remove(list5[removeitem5])
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var6:
       for a in list6:
         print ("• {}".format(a))
       print ("Which item would you like to remove?")
       removeitem6 = int(input())
       removeitem6 = removeitem6+1
       list6.remove(list6[removeitem6])
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var7:
       for a in list7:
         print ("• {}".format(a))
       print ("Which item would you like to remove?")
       removeitem7 = int(input())
       removeitem7 = removeitem7+1
       list7.remove(list7[removeitem7])
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var8:
       for a in list8:
         print ("• {}".format(a))
       print ("Which item would you like to remove?")
       removeitem8 = int(input())
       removeitem8 = removeitem8+1
       list8.remove(list8[removeitem1])
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var9:
       for a in list9:
         print ("• {}".format(a))
       print ("Which item would you like to remove?")
       removeitem9 = int(input())
       removeitem9 = removeitem9+1
       list9.remove(list9[removeitem9])
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()
     elif listselect == var10:
       for a in list10:
         print ("• {}".format(a))
       print ("Which item would you like to remove?")
       removeitem10 = int(input())
       removeitem10 = removeitem10+1
       list10.remove(list10[removeitem10])
       time.sleep(2)
       function1()


listamount = int(("0"))
print ("Would you like a tutorial? y/n")
tutorial = input()
if tutorial == 'y':
  print ("INSERT_TUTORIAL_HERE")
  time.sleep(0.25)
elif tutorial == 'n':
  print ("Well aren't you clever?")
  time.sleep(0.25)
else:
  print ("Please enter y/n ")
  time.sleep(1)
  exec(open("main.py").read())
print ("What would you like your list to be called?")
var1 = input()
keepgoing1 = True
list1 = []

while keepgoing1:
  print ("Add item to list: {}. ".format(var1))
  newitem1 = input()
  if newitem1 == "stop":
    keepgoing1 = False
    listamount = listamount+1
  elif newitem1 == "done":
    keepgoing1 = False
    listamount = listamount+1
  else:
    list1.append(newitem1)
    print (list1)
createlist2 = input("Create another list? y/n ")
if createlist2 == 'n':
  function1()
elif createlist2 == 'y':
  print ("What would you like your second list to be called?")
  var2 = input()
  keepgoing2 = True
  list2 = []

  while keepgoing2:
    print ("Add item to list: {}. ".format(var2))
    newitem2 = input()
    if newitem2 == "stop":
      keepgoing2 = False
      listamount = listamount+1
    elif newitem2 == "done":
      keepgoing2 = False
      listamount = listamount+1
    else:
      list2.append(newitem2)
      print (list2)
  createlist3 = input("Create another list? y/n ")
  if createlist3 == 'n':
    function1()
  elif createlist3 == 'y':
   print ("What would you like your third list to be called?")
   keepgoing3 = True
   list3 = []

   while keepgoing3:
     print ("Add item to list: {}. ".format(var3))
     newitem3 = input()
     if newitem3 == "stop":
       keepgoing3 = False
       listamount = listamount+1
     elif newitem3 == "done":
       keepgoing3 = False
       listamount = listamount+1
     else:
       list3.append(newitem3)
       print (list3)
   createlist4 = input("Create another list? y/n ")
   if createlist4 == 'n':
     function1()
   elif createlist4 == 'y':
     print ("What would you like your fourth list to be called?")
     keepgoing4 = True
     list4 = []

     while keepgoing4:
       newitem4 = input()
       if newitem4 == "stop":
         keepgoing4 = False
         listamount = listamount+1
       elif newitem4 == "done":
         keepgoing4 = False
         listamount = listamount+1
       else:
         list4.append(newitem4)
         print (list4)
     createlist5 = input("Create another list? y/n ")
     if createlist5 == 'n':
       function1()
     elif createlist5 == 'y':
       print ("What would you like your fifth list to be called?")
       keepgoing5 = True
       list5 = []

       while keepgoing5:
         newitem5 = input()
         if newitem5 == 'stop':
           keepgoing5 = False
           listamount = listamount+1
         elif newitem5 == 'done':
           keepgoing5 = False
           listamount = listamount+1
         else:
           list5.append(newitem5)
           print (list5)
       createlist6 = input("Create another list? y/n ")
       if createlist6 == 'n':
         function1()
       elif createlist6 == 'y':
          print ("What would you like your sixth list to be called?")
          keepgoing6 = True
          list6 = []

          while keepgoing6:
            newitem6 = input()
            if newitem6 == 'stop':
              keepgoing6 = False
              listamount = listamount+1
            elif newitem6 == 'done':
              keepgoing6 = False
              listamount = listamount+1
            else:
              list6.append(newitem6)
              print (list6)
          createlist7 = input("Create another list? y/n ")
          if createlist7 == 'n':
            function1()
          elif createlist7 == 'y':
            print ("What would you like your seventh list to be called?")
            keepgoing7 = True
            list7 = []

            while keepgoing7:
              newitem7 = input()
              if newitem7 == 'stop':
                keepgoing7 = False
                listamount = listamount+1
              elif newitem7 == 'done':
                keepgoing7 = False
                listamount = listamount+1
              else:
                list7.append(newitem7)
                print (list7)
            createlist8 = input("Create another list? y/n ")
            if createlist == 'n':
              function1()
            elif createlist8 == 'y':
              print ("What would you like your eighth list to be called?")
              keepgoing8 = True
              list8 = []

              while keepgoing8:
                newitem8 = input()
                if newitem8 == 'stop':
                  keepgoing8 = False
                  listamount = listamount+1
                elif newitem8 == 'done':
                  keepgoing8 = False
                  listamount = listamount+1
                else:
                  list8.append(newitem8)
                  print (list8)
              createlist9 = input("Create another list? y/n ")
              if createlist9 == 'n':
                function1()
              elif createlist9 == 'y':
                print ("What would you like your ninth list to be called?")
                keepgoing9 = True
                list9 = []

                while keepgoing9:
                  newitem9 = input()
                  if newitem9 == 'stop':
                    keepgoing9 = False
                    listamount = listamount+1
                  elif newitem == 'done':
                    keepgoing9 = False
                    listamount = listamount+1
                  else:
                    list9.append(newitem9)
                    print (list9)
                createlist10 = input("Create another list? y/n")
                if createlist10 == 'n':
                  function1()
                elif createlist10 == 'y':
                  print ("What would you like your tenth list to be called?")
                  keepgoing10 = True
                  list10 = []

                  while keepgoing10:
                    newitem10 = input()
                    if newitem10 == 'stop':
                      keepgoing10 = False
                      listamount = listamount+1
                    if newitem10 == 'done':
                      keepgoing10 = False
                      listamount = listamount+1
                    else:
                      list10.append(newitem10)
                      print (list10)
                      print ("I think ten lists is enough...")
                      print ("commercial use detected, please buy a licence.")
```

Comment: remove function1() from every loop inside function1(). this is preventing the loop to work properly. it is asking for "please enter a function" every time you are calling it inside each loop because of which you must be writing "view" or "edit" every time .